# Error after upload the file

Tags: php

I have two files, upload.php:

```
<?php

$validExt=array("txt","xml");
$ext=end(explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']));
if(($_FILES['file']['type']=='text/plain') ||($_FILES['file']['type']=='text/xml')&&($_FILES['file']['size']<1000)&& in_array($ext,$validExt)){
    if($_FILES['file']['error']>0){
        echo "ERROR!";
    }else{
        echo "Name: ".$_FILES['file']['name']."<br>";
        echo "Type: ".$_FILES['file']['type']."<br>";
        echo "Size: ".$_FILES['file']['size']."<br>";
        echo "Tmp name: ".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']."<br>";
    }
}else{
    echo "wrong file!";

}


?>
```

And the second one index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
        <input name="file" type="file"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Wyslij" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When i try to upload the file i get an error and good answer. 
Error:
Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in D:\wamp\www\php_z\upload\upload.php on line 4

I'm a beginner in php but can someone explain me what to do to solve this problem wth errror?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) takes an array that can be passed by reference since it modifies the internal pointer of the array. What you've passed it is the return of [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). Since the return of explode isn't necessarily a variable, it can't be passed by reference. What you should do is set a variable containing the return of `explode(...)` and then pass that to `end()`.

```
$validExt = array("txt", "xml");
$ext = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
$ext = end($ext);
```

Comment: Ah I see, so it is new since 5.4
http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php
Good to know :)